# TF30046 Error after restoring TFS database to new server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, backup

I am using TFS 2012. I wanted to test how I can recover from server failure or any hardware failure, so I shifted TFS to a new server.

I followed [an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops-2022) to restore it. What I did is:

1. I had full backup of TFS_configuration and all other collection databases.(backup taken using TFSbackup.exe)
2. On the new server, I installed all the software (such as TFS 2012, SQL Server, etc).
3. Created all the Windows user accounts that were on the old server.
4. When I checked the new server, it had a default collection created, which was mapped to the SQL server which I installed.
5. I deleted that default collection and restored all databases of my old TFS server (TFS_configuration and all other collection database); the backup was restored using TFSrestore.exe)

6, When I check the TFS administrative console it has all the collections that my old server had. But when I click on Administrative security, group membership, etc., I get this error:

> TF30046: The instance information does not match. Team Foundation expected 368f7830-1c67-4c4c-8bc4-ba3d5b5a5543 which was not found. Please contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

In [this link](https://devtipsandtricks.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/tfs-express-2012-tf30046-the-instance-information-does-not-match/) it was mentioned to change the service host id in the database table, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Had the same problem today. You write "it was mentioned to change service host id in table" - so I assume, you changed the ID in the table? I changed the ID in the web.config to match the one in the host table and it worked...

Answer (score 2):

You incorrectly configured TFS (in fact it created a default collection). If you read [Move Team Foundation Server from one hardware configuration to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops-2022) carefully, you have to run the Application Tier-only Configuration Wizard *after* restoring the databases.