# TF30046: Issues with migrating TFS server

Tags: tfs

In the process of trying to migrate the TFS - Server 2013 to a new location we encountered an issue.

```
TF30046: The instance information does not match. Team Foundation expected xxx which was not found.
```

We tried to change the HostID in the DataBase as suggested by this link:
https://devtipsandtricks.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/tfs-express-2012-tf30046-the-instance-information-does-not-match/

but this did not resolve the issue. Because when I do that, I have another error stating the collection is `in the process of being serviced`.

Steps taken

- Fresh OS
- New install of SQL
- Restored database from backup (all was well)

Comment: How did you make database backups?

Comment: @ds19 They are automatic generated every day.

Comment: The old server kinda broke, we are trying to get a current back-up now. I've read [somewhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-across-domains#backup-dbs) You need to Stop TFS Services first and backup afterwards.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621844/error-after-restoring-tfs-database-to-new-hardware ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I made it work.

Thnx to @ds19 for making me revist the documentation again.

The fix was:

1. Restore the database from backup
2. Doing the Application Tier only wizard

Comment: In my case I was migrating tfs 2012 to another tfs 2012 on a different server. The original was Windows Server 2008R2 & the destination was Windows Server 2016. I installed tfs 2012 with service pack 4 but it seems the original did not have all the service packs installed. So I had to run the update wizard instead of Application Tier only wizard.